# How does the ReLU function work for z < 0?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, gradient-descent

[image]

I  get that for z > 0 , the gradient of the ReLU function is 1 , hence the gradient descent algorithm can proceed faster. 
But what happens if z < 0? How would the gradient descent algorithm proceed then?

Comment: Gradient descent still works.  It does not adjust any input weights on a ReLU neuron with an activation of less than zero.  The neurons which contributed to the network output (i.e. those with z > 0) get weight adjustments.  If z < 0 on all the training inputs the neuron never contributes to the output and is effectively pruned from the network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both back and forward propagation are faster to evaluate for the same reason: relu doesn't need any calculation. The gradient is either 0 on the negative value or 1 for the positive.

I wouldn't say that the gradient descent moves faster due to gradient being 1 on the positive values. It's only the calculations are faster.

Comment: +1, it would be even better with more explanations.

Answer (score 6):

The gradient is zero, which means nothing gets backpropagated through them; the precise value fed to this neuron doesn't matter when $z<0$.  If  a RELU unit is always in the left part of the graph, you get the [dying/dead RELU problem](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/5706/what-is-the-dying-relu-problem-in-neural-networks); this is one of the reasons that people have looked for alternatives to RELUs.

Sigmoid activations get a similar problem at both ends; even though they're not *exactly* flat like a RELU, they're close enough once you get to +/- 5 or so.

Comment: +1, i think this is better than accepted answer.

Comment: @HaitaoDu I'm quite confused in the case of ```z<0```. What if the input is positive and its weight was negative (randomized initially), then that neuron would get deactivated (no weight update) even though it could be essential. Am I missing something here?